# How to force rendering of street view when building interior view exists?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

How can I make Google StreetView API show the exterior of the building (the view from the road) rather than the building interior when both are present for a given set of coordinates?

```
<div id="panoramadiv" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var lat_lng2 =  new google.maps.LatLng(37.79416, -122.423539);

var streetViewOptions2 = {
position: lat_lng2,
scrollwheel: false
};

var div = document.getElementById('panoramadiv');
var street_view2 = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(div, streetViewOptions2);
</script>
```

This example renders the interior of K-One Fitness rather than the street view of 2001 Van Ness Ave, San Francisco, CA as expected.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9C8wM/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geocoder is returning a "rooftop" geocode.  The only way to look at the outside of the building is to find a Streetview location on the street.  To do that get directions to the address, then calculate the heading from the location on the street to the rooftop.

[Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_Streetview_lookAtB.html?snaptoroad=2001%20Van%20Ness,%20San%20Francisco,CA)

Comment: Wow, that's a lot more complex than I expected.  But thanks for the example solution.  Will start working on it.